# Java 2D Game KeyListener Not Fulfilling It's Destiny

Tags: java, swing, 2d, keylistener

I've decided it's time to take my programming to the next step: Making A Game. So far I've been able to code everything alright, maybe having to Google some stuff I'm not too familiar with, but I feel like it **should** work. The graphics are being painted and all that's nice and dandy, but when it comes to the Key Listeners, that's where things went wrong. I made an inner class that implemented Key Listener, then added it in the Board constructor. I guess you'll just have to look at the code but it's pretty long and a bit messy. This is my first time doing this, so some stuff is probably unnecessary and I may just be forgetting something really obvious.

Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JFrame{
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Game();
}
public Game(){

    add(new Board());

    setTitle("Hi mom");
    setSize(555,330);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Board Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

Image background;
Player p;
int k;
boolean moving;

public Board() {

    setFocusable(true);

    Timer timer = new Timer(25, this);
    timer.start();

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/map.png"));
    background = img.getImage();

    addKeyListener(new Kl());

    p = new Player();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(), p.setX(30), p.setY(187), null);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (k == 'W' && moving == true) {
        p.move(0,-5);
    }
    if (k == 'S' && moving == true) {
        p.move(0,5);
    }
    if (k == 'D' && moving == true) {
        p.move(5,0);
    }
    if (k == 'A' && moving == true) {
        p.move(-5,0);
    }

    repaint();
}

public class Kl implements KeyListener {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        k = e.getKeyCode();
        moving = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        moving = false;
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}
}
```

Player Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Player{
int x, y;
Image player;
public Player(){
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/player.png"));
    player = img.getImage();
}
public Image getPlayer(){
    return player;
}
public void move(int x, int y){
    this.x += x;
}
public int setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
    return x;
}
public int setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
    return y;
}
}
```

Comment: See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for some ideas with creating your Key Bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `KeyListener` will only trigger key events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has keyboard focus.  Simply calling `setFocsuable` isn't enough.  This just means that the component is "capable" of receiving keyboard focus, not that it has it.

Instead, you should be using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which has the means to over come this limitation, amongst other things.

Comment: I tried using Key Bindings but it started getting a bit messy, but of course I will try again!

Comment: Personally, I would approach this from a OO perspective, starting with a simple "Move" action, which takes two parameters which describes the x/y delta (changes) that should be applied.  That way, for each movement, you could use this class, passing it different deltas based on the required movement and/or create individual movement actions (ie up, down, left, right), which extend from this base class, but that's up to you ;)